# ASP.Net: Fail to put <script> inside <head>

Tags: html, asp.net, master-pages

I put some `<script>` inside `<head>` tag in my master page. But rendered result in browser, they are put at bottom of `<body>`. Rebuilding the application doesn't work, neither does cleaning browser cache. Any idea? Thanks.

```
<head><script type="text/javascript">alert();</script></head>
```

Comment: can you post the code ?

Comment: Just common `<head>` tag, I put `<script>` inside it.
Something like: `<head><script type="text/javascript">alert();</script></head>`

Comment: I asked about the code because can be a mistype problem with a tag or something similar or maybe a 3rd party script or something

Comment: add code from OP's comment

Comment: What version of ASP.NET? Individual WebForms, or are you using a master page?

Comment: @TiesonT.: ASP.Net 4.5.2. Webform using master page, as I said in the question.

Comment: @maspai did you tried my solution?

Comment: @Webruster: I didn't, because it uses Javascript, while I'm looking for solution in ASP.Net way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `appendChild` to add script to `Head`. Something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(script);
```

**Edit:**

As you mentioned in your Comments ,

Here Take a look at [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/johnkatsiotis/archive/2008/08/08/add-scripts-to-head-dynamically.aspx) article:

It provides a nice clean way to add a script to the head element using an extension method.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for solution using ASP.Net code, not Javascript.